# Ajax request working only every other time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just starting out with ajax...trying to submit a form with ajax through a post request. For some reason, the code I wrote works exactly every other time.  When I first submit the form, it's processed through ajax.  When I submit again, javascript is not called and the form is submitted with a normal post request.  When I submit a third time, ajax works again.  And so on.  Any idea how to fix this to make ajax work every time?

```
function contact_submit() {

alert('starting');

var data = {
    name: $('#id_name').val(),
    email: $('#id_email').val(),
    title: $('#id_title').val(),
    message: $('#id_message').val(),
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
};

$('#contact_form').load("/contact/?ajax", data, function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        $("#contact_form").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      }
});

alert('load was performed');

return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
//*$(document).submit(contact_submit);
$(document).on("submit","form",contact_submit);
});
```

Comment: Solved it using a workaround.  Before, I was regenerating the submit button every time with my ajax request, and I think the event handler wasn't attached to the regenerated submit element.  I moved the submit outside the target of ajax request, and it started working every time.

Comment: You should include your own answer in this thread and mark it off as the correct one.  Useful for future readers

Comment: Yep, I have to wait 8 hours because I have low rep.  Will do when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using a workaround. Before, I was regenerating the submit button every time with my ajax request, and I think the event handler wasn't attached to the regenerated submit element. I moved the submit outside the target of ajax request, and it started working every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cancel the event using `return false` if you attached it on the `document` level. By the time it has propagated to the `document` level the form is already submitting. You should be attaching the event to the form specifically (as you have commented out) and the reattaching it again on success event of the `load()` call.

Comment: I tried that, and still got the same alternating behavior (although I deleted that from my code sample)

Comment: @vasek1 it likely means attaching the event second time have failed due to an exception in your code.